# Como pegar uma image em uma pasta na raiz do projeto?

Tags: c#

Estou tentando pegar uma imagem que está dentro de uma pasta no projeto para usar com "Default" caso algum usuário não adicione a foto na hora do cadastro, porém ao tentar passar a url, da erro porquê o I.O não consegue localizar a mesma.

Segue local da imagem no projeto:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Por linha de código, eu consegui passando assim:

```
if (usuario.imagem.Length == 0)
{
    string path = @"C:\Pro\028\webIRMA\Content\dist\img\avatarPadrao.png";

    using (Image image = Image.FromFile(path))
    {
        using (MemoryStream m = new MemoryStream())
        {
            image.Save(m, image.RawFormat);
            byte[] imageBytes = m.ToArray();;
            Session["ImagePerfil"] = imageBytes;
        }
    }
}
else
{
    Session["ImagePerfil"] = usuario.imagem;
}
```

Porém isso é `localhost`, quando é passado pra outro servidor, no caso de produção pode mudar o local do projeto,ai tentei algo como abaixo, mas sem sucesso:

```
string path = @"~/webIRMA/Content/dist/img/avatarPadrao.png";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use o [`HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath`](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.web.httpserverutility.mappath?view=netframework-4.8)

```
string path = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("Content\dist\img\avatarPadrao.png");
```

É necessário adicionar a referência para o `System.Web` para usa-lo.